# Can't create Rancher server tables when setup Rancher server HA cluster on AWS

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, cluster-computing, high-availability, rancher

## Versions

- docker version:

  ```
  Client:
   Version:      17.09.0-ce
   API version:  1.32
   Go version:   go1.8.3
   Git commit:   afdb6d4
   Built:        Tue Sep 26 22:41:23 2017
   OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

  Server:
   Version:      17.09.0-ce
   API version:  1.32 (minimum version 1.12)
   Go version:   go1.8.3
   Git commit:   afdb6d4
   Built:        Tue Sep 26 22:42:49 2017
   OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
   Experimental: false
  ```
- rancher server version: `rancher/server:stable`
- OS:

  ```
  NAME="CentOS Linux"
  VERSION="7 (Core)"
  ID="centos"
  ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"
  VERSION_ID="7"
  PRETTY_NAME="CentOS Linux 7 (Core)"
  ANSI_COLOR="0;31"
  CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:centos:centos:7"
  HOME_URL="https://www.centos.org/"
  BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.centos.org/"

  CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT="CentOS-7"
  CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT_VERSION="7"
  REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="centos"
  REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION="7"
  ```

Using Rancher server HA feature now. Prepared a db cluster, using `AWS RDS Aurora cluster`.

I can connect the cluste IP(`AWS RDS`) from Rancher server host(`AWS EC2`) by `mysql cli`, but use this Rancher server installation command seems can’t create tables in the database:

```
$ docker run -d --restart=unless-stopped -p 8080:8080 -p 9345:9345 rancher/server:stable --db-host [DB_CLUSTER_HOST] --db-port 3306 --db-user [USERNAME] --db-pass [PASSWORD] --db-name [DB_NAME] --advertise-address [CURRENT_IP]
```

From the `docker inspect` way to see the running Rancher server container, the arguments were been set correctly:

```
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                   COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                                      NAMES
f5b8ff32907c        rancher/server:stable   "/usr/bin/entry --..."   2 minutes ago       Up 2 minutes        0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp, 3306/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9345->9345/tcp   priceless_beaver

$ docker inspect f5b8
[
    {
        "Id": "f5b8ff32907c6e3158b424c7e2ba5b320763a5a5da807927a096d45ae700a30f",
        "Created": "2017-12-06T04:41:08.498666156Z",
        "Path": "/usr/bin/entry",
        "Args": [
            "--db-host",
            "[DB_HOST]",
            "--db-port",
            "3306",
            "--db-user",
            "[DB_USER]",
            "--db-pass",
            "[DB_PASS]",
            "--db-name",
            "[DB_NAME]",
            "--advertise-address",
            "[CURRENT_IP]"
        ],
...
```

From container log, got:

```
$ docker logs [CONTAINER_ID]
...
07:42:32.965 [main] ERROR i.c.p.a.sources.LazyJDBCSource - Failed to get connection to database, will retry for 5 minutes
07:42:40.061 [pollingConfigurationSource] ERROR i.c.p.a.sources.LazyJDBCSource - Failed to get connection to database, will retry for 5 minutes
07:42:47.077 [main] ERROR i.c.p.a.sources.LazyJDBCSource - Failed to get connection to database, will retry for 5 minutes
07:42:54.093 [pollingConfigurationSource] ERROR i.c.p.a.sources.LazyJDBCSource - Failed to get connection to database, will retry for 5 minutes
07:43:01.109 [main] ERROR i.c.p.a.sources.LazyJDBCSource - Failed to get connection to database, will retry for 5 minutes
07:43:08.125 [pollingConfigurationSource] ERROR i.c.p.a.sources.LazyJDBCSource - Failed to get connection to database, will retry for 5 minutes
07:43:15.213 [main] ERROR i.c.p.a.sources.LazyJDBCSource - Failed to get connection to database, will retry for 5 minutes
07:43:22.229 [pollingConfigurationSource] ERROR i.c.p.a.sources.LazyJDBCSource - Failed to get connection to database, will retry for 5 minutes
07:43:29.245 [main] ERROR i.c.p.a.sources.LazyJDBCSource - Failed to get connection to database, will retry for 5 minutes
07:43:36.261 [pollingConfigurationSource] ERROR i.c.p.a.sources.LazyJDBCSource - Failed to get connection to database, will retry for 5 minutes
07:43:43.277 [main] ERROR i.c.p.a.sources.LazyJDBCSource - Failed to get connection to database, will retry for 5 minutes

$ docker logs [CONTAINER_ID] -f
...
Caused by: java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not connect to address=(host=[CLUSTER_HOST])(port=3306)(type=master) : Connection timed out
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.ExceptionMapper.get(ExceptionMapper.java:137)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.ExceptionMapper.getException(ExceptionMapper.java:101)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.ExceptionMapper.throwException(ExceptionMapper.java:91)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:109)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DriverConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverConnectionFactory.java:38)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:582)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.validateConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1556)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1545)
    ... 102 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.dao.QueryException: Could not connect to address=(host=[CLUSTER_HOST])(port=3306)(type=master) : Connection timed out
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractConnectProtocol.connectWithoutProxy(AbstractConnectProtocol.java:827)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.Utils.retrieveProxy(Utils.java:469)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:104)
    ... 106 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractConnectProtocol.connect(AbstractConnectProtocol.java:371)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractConnectProtocol.connectWithoutProxy(AbstractConnectProtocol.java:823)
    ... 108 common frames omitted
```

But why failed to connect database in this way?

Comment: The reason was `DNS`! Change docker daemon set a DNS: https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/linux-postinstall/#specify-dns-servers-for-docker